# Bin formation in a R data.frame

Tags: r, binning

I have a data.frame with two columns:

```
category quantity
a          20
b          30
c          100
d          10
e          1
f          23
g          3
h          200
```

I need to write a function with two parameters: `dataframe`, `bin_size` which runs a `cumsum` over the quantity column, does a split of the subsequent row if the the `cumsum` exceeds the `bin_size` and adds a running bin number as an additional column.

Say, by entering this:

```
function(dataframe, 50)
```

in the above example should give me:

```
category    quantity    cumsum  bin_nbr
a            20        20         1
b            30        50         1
c            50        50         2
c            50        50         3
d            10        10         4
e            1         11         4
f           23         34         4
g            3         37         4
h            13        50         4
h            50        50         5
h            50        50         6
h            50        50         7
h            37        37         8
```

Explanation:

```
row a + b sum up to 50 --> bin_nbr 1
row c is 100 -> split into 2 rows @ 50 -> bin nbr 2, bin_nbr 3
row d,e,f,g sum up to 37 -> bin_nbr 4
I need another 13 from row h to fill in bin_nbr 4 to 50
The rest of the remaining quantity from h will be spitted into 4 bins -> bin_nbr 5, 6, 7, 8
```

Comment: Please don't forget to [accept](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) the answer that solved your problem and that you liked best. Also consider voting answers.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't think of a clean way to do this with apply/data.table etc since you have an inter-row dependency and a changing size data frame.  You can probably do it in an iterative/recursive manner, but I felt it would be quicker to figure out to just write the loop.  One challenge is that it is difficult to know the final size of your object, so this is likely to be slow.  You can mitigate the problem somewhat by switching from a df to a matrix (code should work fine, except transform bits) if performance is an issue in this application.

```
fun <- function(df, binsize){
  df$cumsum <- cumsum(df$quantity)
  df$bin <- 1
  i <- 1
  repeat {
    if((extra <- (df[i, "cumsum"] - binsize)) > 0) { # Bin finished halfway through
      top <- if(i > 1L) df[1L:(i - 1L), ] else df[0L, ]
      mid <- transform(df[i, ], quantity=quantity-extra, cumsum=cumsum-extra)
      bot <- transform(df[i, ], quantity=extra, cumsum=extra, bin=bin + 1L)
      end <- if(i >= nrow(df)) df[0L, ] else df[(i + 1L):nrow(df), ]
      end <- transform(end, cumsum=cumsum(end$quantity) + extra, bin=bin + 1L)
      df <- rbind(top, mid, bot, end)
    } else if (extra == 0 && nrow(df) > i) {  # Bin finished cleanly
      df[(i + 1L):nrow(df), ]$cumsum <- df[(i + 1L):nrow(df), ]$cumsum - binsize
      df[(i + 1L):nrow(df), ]$bin <- df[(i + 1L):nrow(df), ]$bin + 1L
    }
    if(nrow(df) < (i <- i + 1)) break
  }
  rownames(df) <- seq(len=nrow(df))
  df
}
fun(df, binsize) 

#    category quantity cumsum bin
# 1         a       20     20   1
# 2         b       30     50   1
# 3         c       50     50   2
# 4         c       50     50   3
# 5         d       10     10   4
# 6         e        1     11   4
# 7         f       23     34   4
# 8         g        3     37   4
# 9         h       13     50   4
# 10        h       50     50   5
# 11        h       50     50   6
# 12        h       50     50   7
# 13        h       37     37   8
```

Comment: Thank you BrodieG. For my dataset of about 10K records the performance is ok.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution with a loop:

```
DF <- read.table(text="category quantity
a          20
b          30
c          100
d          10
e          1
f          23
g          3
h          200", header=TRUE)

bin_size <- 50
n_bin <- ceiling(sum(DF$quantity)/bin_size)

DF$bin <- findInterval(cumsum(DF$quantity)-1, c(0, seq_len(n_bin)*50))
DF$cumsum <- cumsum(DF$quantity)

result <- lapply(seq_along(DF[,1]), function(i, df) {
  if (i==1) {
    d <- df[i, "bin"]
  } else {
    d <- df[i, "bin"]-df[i-1, "bin"]
  }
  if (d > 1) {    
    res <- data.frame(
      category = df[i, "category"],
      bin_nbr = df[i, "bin"]-seq_len(d+1)+1
    )        
    res[,"quantity"] <- bin_size
    if (i!=1) {
      res[nrow(res),"quantity"] <- df[i-1, "bin"]*bin_size-df[i-1, "cumsum"]
    }  else {
      res[nrow(res),"quantity"] <- 0
    }
    res[1,"quantity"] <- df[i, "quantity"]-sum(res[-1,"quantity"])
    return(res[res$quantity > 0,])
  } else {
    return(data.frame(
      category = df[i, "category"],
      quantity = df[i, "quantity"],
      bin_nbr = df[i, "bin"]
    ))
  }
}, df=DF)

res <- do.call(rbind, result)
res <- res[order(res$category, res$bin_nbr),]
library(plyr)
res <- ddply(res, .(bin_nbr), transform, cumsum=cumsum(quantity))
res

#    category quantity bin_nbr cumsum
# 1         a       20       1     20
# 2         b       30       1     50
# 3         c       50       2     50
# 4         c       50       3     50
# 5         d       10       4     10
# 6         e        1       4     11
# 7         f       23       4     34
# 8         g        3       4     37
# 9         h       13       4     50
# 10        h       50       5     50
# 11        h       50       6     50
# 12        h       50       7     50
# 13        h       37       8     37
```

Answer (score 0):

This amounts to merging the bin boundaries with the data which gives this loop-free solution:

```
library(zoo)

fun <- function(DF, binsize = 50) {
  nr <- nrow(DF)
  DF2 <- data.frame(cumsum = seq(0, sum(DF$quantity), binsize) + binsize, bin_nbr = 1:nr)
  DF.cs <- transform(DF, cumsum = cumsum(DF$quantity))
  m <- na.locf(merge(DF.cs, DF2, all = TRUE), fromLast = TRUE)
  m$bin_nbr <- as.numeric(m$bin_nbr)
  cs <- as.numeric(m$cumsum)
  m$quantity <- c(cs[1], diff(cs))
  m$cumsum <- ave(m$quantity, m$bin_nbr, FUN = cumsum)
  na.omit(m)[c("category", "quantity", "cumsum", "bin_nbr")]
}
```

giving:

```
> fun(DF)
   category quantity cumsum bin_nbr
1         a       20     20       1
2         b       30     50       1
3         c       50     50       2
4         c       50     50       3
5         d       10     10       4
6         e        1     11       4
7         f       23     34       4
8         g        3     37       4
9         h       13     50       4
10        h       50     50       5
11        h       50     50       6
12        h       50     50       7
13        h       37     37       8
```

*Note:*  For purposes of reproducing the result above this is the input we used:

```
Lines <- "category quantity
a          20
b          30
c          100
d          10
e          1
f          23
g          3
h          200
"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE, as.is = TRUE)
```

*REVISION* An error in the code was corrected.

Comment: Running your function I am receiving a result with 64 rows instead of 13. What is wrong?

Comment: I must have pasted an earlier version into SO.  I have repasted it and ran it from a fresh R session just to be sure that the code above does give the output above.  I also included the input in reproducible form at the end so be sure you are using that too.  Try it now.